# PHP mysql returns bool(true) even when field is not in table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 $sql = "UPDATE prelaunch SET email_verified = true WHERE email_verification_link = '$cKey' AND email_verified = '0'";

 $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 var_dump($res);
```

`bool(true)` is the var_dump even when the `email_verification_link` is not a valid key in the table...? It does update the `email_verified` value to 1 if the `email_verification_link` key is valid.

When the key is not valid it still returns `bool(true)`.. How can I check if key is valid before updating table in a single sql statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning `true` means the query succeeded. Returning `false` means the query failed. Finding no rows is not a failure. Failures are things like broken SQL syntax that means your query can't run.

Instead, check the `mysqli_affected_rows` function:

```
$rows = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
```

Comment: +1 and by the way, affected rows is the number of rows that actually changed as a result of your update. So if your query's conditions matched a bunch of rows, but they *already* had `email_verified=true`, then you would see 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

well, the query returns true because the `UPDATE` command was executed successfully. you can find out how many rows have been affected by your command by using
[mysqli_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).